# Can Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform Version 6.1.2 be used?

Tags: uwp

Did anyone succeed in uploading a package to the store using Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform Version 6.1.2 without errors? If so, can you give details or a copy of a simple demo project.

I got the error: The declared package dependency does not exist. Dependency: Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.1. Minimum version: 2.1.26417.0.

Answer (score 0):

It is [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/728) in github. Currently, you need to downgrade to v6.0.8 and then will upload successfully.